# Rails: undefined local variable or method `params'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rails 4.2.6 app. I need to transfer a table params from the controller to the model. Doing this I'm getting this error `undefined local variable or method 'params'` I'm trying to transfer the next line of code `html += params[:table_data].gsub('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>', '&#10004;') if params[:table_data].present?` into the model in this lines of codes:

```
if !element.nil?
          html += "<td class=\"soa-element text-center\" form_id=\"#{form.id}\" visit_id=\"#{visit.id}\" id=\"#{element.id}\">"
          html += params[:table_data].gsub('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>', '&#10004;') if params[:table_data].present?
          html += "</td>"
        else
          html += "<td class=\"soa-element\" form_id=\"#{form.id}\" visit_id=\"#{visit.id}\" id=\"0\"></td>"
        end
```

Here above I'm getting the error but I cannot figure out was I'm doing wrong.

Next Pastebin is the model and the controller related to this issue:

https://pastebin.com/cVy9QRCy

https://pastebin.com/ApZSgYFE

If I keep as was original my app still working but I cannot have table elements inside the controller and I need to transfer the same to the model. I need to understand what wrong I'm doing.

Comment: Curious whether any of the provided answers were helpful...

Comment: @jvillian the answers gave me a general idea so were helpful but I still need to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer tells you correctly that you probably don't want to do it that way, but in case you really want to, the thing that you have to do is make `@params = the_params` or in the same way set a variable with `@` sign and that variable will be available in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be useful. Transfering variables from Controller to views you should be using @varaible...

If you are transfer to a model it has to be done within a function in the Model.rb file.

Comment: Yes, what I have to do actually is put that line under a model and call it in the controller. as an example, I have this on the same controller `html += PdfReport.page_break`which is for the export to PDF. I would like to do something similar like 'Class.soa_table_export' with that line of code but still I have an error about this params undefined.

Comment: because they are undefined, you have to do `@params = something` in controller to define it

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you already have an example of a method that receives the params, here:

```
def update_state(params)
  self.update(params)
  self.reload
  self.next_state_version
  self.save
end
```

And example of how you call such a method from the controller, here:

```
def update_status
  find_token
  if @token.nil?
    flash[:error] = "The changes were not saved as the edit lock has timed out."
  else
    @study_version.update_state(the_params)
    AuditTrail.update_item_event(current_user, @study.identifier, @study_version.semantic_version, "Study version updated")
    @token.release
  end
  redirect_to history_study_path(@study)
end
```

So, in your model, do:

```
def soa(params)
  ...
end
```

And in your controller:

```
def soa
  @study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
  render text: @study_version.soa(the_params).html_safe
end
```

Having said that, I would also add that a lot of this logic and code should, IMO, be moved into service objects and presenters. You have way too much (again, IMO) going on in your controllers and pushing that into your models isn't that much better. You're just stuffing your junk in another drawer.

Answer (score -1):

You don't transfer params from controllers to views. Use instance variable instead. If you declare a variable params in your controller it will be available in your view.

You need to clear your MVC concepts first.

Comment: Could you please make me a simple example of that? 
What I was asked to do in in project at my office was to transfer that line of code from the controller to the model. Is it possible?